# How to return a set of persisted objects?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, entitymanager

I have a class with a method for creating a customer object via entity manager. I want to add another method which will return a set of created objects; how can I do that in my case? For instance, I have the following code:

```
public class DefaultCoreRepository implements CoreRepository {

private EntityManager entityManager;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "crm-db")
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

private <T> T persist(T entity) {
    entityManager.persist(entity);
    return entity;
}

public void createCustomer(Customer customer) {
    persist(customer);
}

public Set<Customer> getCustomers() {
    //Code to be written here
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read the official JPA tutorial first : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html

Comment: I have done that before starting this project. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a query like this and convert List to Set:

```
public Set<Customer> getCustomers() {
     return new HashSet<Customer>(createQuery("select c from Customer c", Customer.class).getResultList());
}
```

Comment: how does this work? I mean, where does the entity manager store all the persisted objects? Thank you for your answer

Comment: It fetches Customer objects from your database, you can read more about that there: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html

Answer (score 5):

Since JPA 2.2 you can also use the Java 8 stream API:

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT customer FROM Customer customer", Customer.class)
            .getResultStream()
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible way could be

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT customer FROM Customer customer",  
                          Customer.class) 
             .getResultList();
```

You can create select queries in your entity manager to get result lists using the JPA